# How to return a character n times before an element react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, random, character

I want to add a random amount of characters before an element, repeat that element 20 times, with a diffrent amount of characters before each time. For example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      Hello World! This is time {i}
      // I want to add a random amount of spaces before the h1 tags above. I also want to repeat that h1 tags 20 times with a different amount of spaces before each h1 tag
    </>
  )
}
```

An example of what I want to return is

Hello World! This is time 1
   Hello World! This is time 2
         Hello World! This is time 3
     Hello World! This is time 4
………
Each with a diffrent amount of spaces.

Comment: Generate a random number in the javascript (i.e. before the return), then create a string and loop the random number of.times inserting `&nbsp;` each time. Then put that string wherever you want it in your element structure with `{spacesString}` or whatever your string is called

Comment: And do the same thing but looping to create an array of H1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function HeaderWithLeadingSpacing({ maxSpacing = 20, num }) {
  const rdn = Math.round(Math.random() * maxSpacing);
  const spacing = Array.from(Array(rdn), () => '\u00A0');
  
  return (
    <h1>{spacing}Hello World! This is number {num}</h1>
  )
}

function App() {
  return Array.from(Array(20), (_, i) => (
    <HeaderWithLeadingSpacing
      maxSpacing={10}
      num={i + 1}
    />
  ));
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



<div id="app"></div>
```

If I have understood correctly, the above code should do the trick.

Comment: I can't pass a space for the char prop, and have it work

Comment: why not? couldn't just do char='&nbsp;'

Comment: OK. Can you please update your answer because I changed the question? Then I might accept it if it works.

Comment: Ok I have added a code snippet to prove it.
(I had to use React.Fragment, since <></> made the script fail)

Comment: What I meant was that on the first h1 tag, there is a 1 somewere, and then there is a 2 on the next h1, and so on

Comment: Ok I really don't get why you are trying to do. Please add a static html example to make it clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225786/discussion-between-rayyan-and-tokimon).