# Indent Entry in React-Select Values

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am new to using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home).  What I am trying to do is conditionally set the indent spacing of some of the drop-down items in the select dropdown box.  Something that would look like this:

[image]

I.e., that is how I would like the items to look in the dropdown menu box.  I.e., if something it is a child, it is indented from its parent and a grandchild would be indented from its parent.  Is this possible in `react-select`?  If so, how would I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Sadly, MarginLeft does not work.
Therefore I used the dynamic spacing method from here: [How to return a character n times before an element react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226243/how-to-return-a-character-n-times-before-an-element-react)

The final code then just looks like

```
const recursivelyListElements = (elist, level) => {
  let returnValues = []
  elist.map(e => {
    const spacing = Array.from(Array(4 * level), () => '\u00A0');
    returnValues.push(
      <option
        value={e.location_id}
        style={{fontSize: (24 - 4 * level) + 'px'}}
        // style={{marginLeft: level + 'em', fontSize: (24 - 4*level)+ 'px'}} marginLeft does not work here
      >
        {spacing}
        {e.title_en}
      </option>
    )
    if (e.children && e.children.length > 0) {
      returnValues.push(...recursivelyListElements(e.children, level + 1))
    }
  })
  return returnValues
}

// ...

<select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    {recursivelyListElements(props.locations, 0)}
</select>
```